# Why can't the mobile game download their assets when they are in the background?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, download

I play a lot of mobile games, and it always bothers me that they must to be in the focus when updating their assets. Those assets are also often packed into a bundle so each update are GB in size.
It's been a long time since mobile been a thing, yet the downloading are still strictly done in the foreground only .
What is causing that? Is it permission limitation? Or some security concern?
Is there a way to download large files into the internal storage in the background on Android?
Also, why must the assetBundle include all the asset in a single file anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, on my mobile phone regardless of what type of app is downloading data, the app continues to download even if I switch to another app, provided that I didn't close it.
Yours stopping the download is probably a personal preference in your phone or app settings.

"Why must the assetBundle include all the asset in a single file anyway?"
There is no such rule, in fact you can create a bundle file for every single asset, which is an interesting idea but not very practical, many problems can happen cause of spamming the user network with requests, with some probably timing out, being throttled etc.

So you'd have to package some in one bundle, its all about packaging the assets that need each other in one bundle, if the size gets big, slice the bundle into smaller bundles.

The bottom line is that there is no general rule for assetbundle size and you really need to do what makes more sense for your project.

Comment: As far as the mobile games I play. when they have assets update that's not bond to the base client, you have to keep the game open to keep the update going.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons might include:

- Allow the user decide when to download (probably just wifi)
- The user can control the data is transferred
- The user knows what is consuming data (people concerned with privacy)
- New OS versions doesn't allow download data on the background (when the application is soft closed). User have to change the permission.
- Battery saver won't allow download data on the background either, user can change the permission.
- For privacy and transparency they let the user know what they are downloading because, not experienced user might start to complain the game is using so much data without knowing its an update, so, they might give a bad feedback of the game and that's a really bad thing.
- Probably the game have the option, but the OS doesn't have the permissions active, so it tries until the user open the game.